# Materials on charged black brane

Tags: gravity, resource-recommendations, ads-cft, branes, chemical-potential

Does anyone know some good materials on charged black branes in AdS/CFT and the role of chemical potential in theses cases?

Answer (score 0):

Until today, there is little review literature about AdS/CFT given how young the subject is. This might change soon, when the book of Erdmenger and Ammon apprears. Until then, [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3246) review of Sean Hartnoll is a great reference with much focus on the applications of charged black hole solutions for boundary condensed matter systems. In this review, one can also find references to the original literature. The chemical potential is addressed in chapter 2.3.

Maybe somebody else has another idea.